# Get cell data from entire row from another row

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula

I have filtered a row to get cells that are empty and received the column numbers. I want to receive the actual cell data from another column.

Example: A11 is empty. I receive 11 however I want to receive what’s in cell B11.

Here’s what I used: =FILTER(ROW(A1:A15);ISBLANK(A1:A15))

Comment: You are filtering for empty cells --> then the cell data of the returned cells will be "empty". Or do you need the *address*, e.g. A11 as output?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot to add that I want to get the corresponding value from  row B. So for every cell that’s empty in A I want to receive the value from B. So if A11 is empty I want to receive cell value of B11

Comment: You should update your question then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the values of column B for rows where A is empty:

```
=FILTER(B1:B15,ISBLANK(A1:A15))
```

---

wrong assumption regarding question - but maybe interesting:

To retrieve the address of empty cells, you can use this formula:

```
=FILTER(MAP(A1:A15,LAMBDA(d,CELL("adresse",d))),ISBLANK(A1:A15))
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your answer!! Thanks a lot

Comment: This works as well: `=ADDRESS(FILTER(ROW(A1:A15),A1:A15=""),1)`